# c# htmlagilitypack change tags attribute

Tags: c#

this is my html. how to change each img src :

```
<div class="test">
<div >
    <img src="/ulploads/bla.png" />
    </div>
    bla bla bla 
    <img src="/uploads/bla2.png" />
    <p>
        bla bla bla
    </p>
</div>
```

for example i want the result to be like this :

```
  <div class="test">
<div >
    <img src="domain/ulploads/bla.png" />
    </div>
    bla bla bla 
    <img src="domain/uploads/bla2.png" />
    <p>
        bla bla bla
    </p>
</div>

var description  = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='test']").InnerHtml;
```

and i want that description to be updated version

Comment: what did you try so far?  And what has this to do with c#? As this is clearly html code it is probably either asp.net or javascript in reality depending on if server side wise or clientwise the change. And also like mentioned what did you try os far already?

Comment: i've updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need Replace;

```
string html = @"<div class="test">
<div >
    <img src="/ulploads/bla.png" />
    </div>
    bla bla bla 
    <img src="/uploads/bla2.png" />
    <p>
        bla bla bla
    </p>
</div>";

html = html.Replace("<img src=\"/uploads", "<img src=\"domain/uploads");
```

or Regex.Replace